# How to login with mfa phone number in azure b2c custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to write a custom policy in Azure B2C to login users with their MFA phone number. User can sign up using an email, password and a phone number used for MFA, but they login using their MFA phone number though.

I have found this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number) in the Azure B2C github sample repository, but although I have an existing user registered with an MFA phone number every time I run the sample and login with the phone number it creates a new user instead of logging the existing one.